# Is there a way to count the number of integer elements that lie within the range of a list of integers in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, count, integer

I'm looking for a way to return the counts of a range of integers in a list even if the integer doesn't appear in the list. I've normally used the `table()` function for tasks like this, but in this case it skips over unobserved integers in the list. I am looking for something that fills those instances with zeros. For example:

```
my_vector <- c(4, 0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0)
table(my_vector)
```

gives the following output:

```
0 2 3 4 6 
2 1 2 2 1
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to get an output like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 0 1 2 2 0 1
```

Looking at the documentation for `table()`, I tried adding the `useNA="always"` argument but that just appends a count for the number of missing values in the list to the output. I also tried adding a `row.names` argument with explicit labels (for example, including a "1" label and a "5" label in the case above), but it seems that argument is only used for `as.data.frame()`, which I reckon is built on the `table()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tabulate()`, assuming the vector doesn't contain any negative values. To begin at zero we add one to both arguments:

```
tabulate(my_vector + 1, nbins = max(my_vector) + 1)
[1] 2 0 1 2 2 0 1
```

With names:

```
setNames(tabulate(my_vector + 1, nbins = max(my_vector) + 1), 0:max(my_vector))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 0 1 2 2 0 1
```

Or less efficiently with `table()` by converting the vector to a factor and setting the levels to cover the range of the vector from zero:

```
table(factor(my_vector, levels = 0:max(my_vector)))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 0 1 2 2 0 1
```

And for completeness, a function that works with negative values tabulating from/to zero:

```
tab <- function(x) {
  offset <- abs(min(c(0, x))) + 1
  rnge <- diff(range(c(0, x))) + 1
  setNames(tabulate(x + offset, nbins = rnge), seq(rnge) - offset)
}

tab(c(-4, -4, -3))
-4 -3 -2 -1  0 
 2  1  0  0  0 

tab(c(-2, 2))  
-2 -1  0  1  2 
 1  0  0  0  1 

tab(c(4, 4, 3))
0 1 2 3 4 
0 0 0 1 2
```